# How can I change text of button inside data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I change text of button inside data tables default content.I want to change the text when that button is clicked. ie, view to viewed .How can I do that?

Comment: Show us your code or DEMO.

Comment: get button id and set it's value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by giving save `class` to each button and add click listener:

```
$('.view-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).text("Viewed");
    /*
         Place your custom code here like Ajax request
    */
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3hbgpr/1/)

Comment: This only works for the first page. You need to use delegated event handlers: `$('#example tbody').on('click', '.view-btn', function(){ });`